# How can we assume the asymptotic complexity of 1/2n^2 - 3n

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am trying to understand how asymptotic complexity of the given function is calculated based out of Introduction to algorithms by Thomas Cormen.

In the book we are trying to solve inequality for $f(n) = \frac12n^2-3n$.

It is solved such that $c_1n^2 \leqslant \frac12n^2 - 3n \leqslant c_2n^2$.

Dividing both sides by $n^2$ results in $c_1\leqslant \frac12 - \frac3n\leqslant c_2$.

In the book I cannot understand the below explanation that the author gives. Can someone help me out here ?
[evaluating inequality and calculatin n0 as mentioned in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiWBB.png)

Full text as in the book
[problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7d51.png)

Comment: Dividing both sides by $n^2$ results in $c_1\leqslant \frac12 - \frac3n\leqslant c_2$, not the inequality you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author chooses an initial value $n_0$ of $n$ such that for $n\geqslant n_0$, $f(n)$ is positive.

The value $n_0$ is found solving:
$$f(n) > 0\iff\frac12-\frac3n> 0 \iff \frac12> \frac3n\iff n>6$$

That's the reason for $n_0 = 7$.

Now, note that for $n\geqslant n_0$, $\frac12-\frac3{n_0}\leqslant \frac12-\frac3n$. In order to get $c_1$ such that $c_1\leqslant \frac12-\frac3n$ foreach $n\geqslant n_0$, it suffices to solve:
$$c_1\leqslant \frac12-\frac3{n_0} = \frac12-\frac37 = \frac1{14}$$
That's the reason for $c_1 = \frac1{14}$.

Now, since for all $n$, $\frac12-\frac3n\leqslant \frac12$, we can choose $c_2 = \frac12$.

Comment: thank you for the explanation @nathaniel